Can i call componentWillUnmount (functional component) with current data?
I have a functional component
export const Example = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState<number>(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        return () => {
            console.log("data", data);
            // ----> Here i want current value of data at the componentWillUnmount
        };
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => setData((prev) => prev + 1)}>Inc</button>
            {data}
        </div>
    );
};


Lets say i rendered this component, clicked 5 times at button. Then i unmounting this component. Can i somehow call console.log inside componentWillUnmount ("return" inside "useEffect" for func components) with current (4) value of data?
Note: i can not pass data as a deps in useEffect cause i dont want to see console.log`s with data every time data changes

Technically, you could do it, but I wouldn't recommend that. Why do you want to leverage the unmounting stage?

In my project i have form with many inputs and i need to notify user that his changes did not saved if he leave page, but i store controlled inputs data in redux store, so, when component unmounted data will not be lost, as i need it to be. I could use temp storage but it will be huge. In a word, its very complicated). Btw anwser with refs is helpful.

Yeah, you can use a ref to jot down the latest value of data, then access the ref in the cleanup function.
const [data, setData] = useState<number>(0);
const ref = useRef(data);
ref.current = data;
useEffect(() => {
  return () => {
    console.log("data", ref.current);
  }
}, []);


I think we should not write ref during render; if you move that assignment to useLayoutEffect, that is safest imho.
